# How to retrieve actual Locale/Language

Tags: android, locale

can anyone tell me how I programmatically retrieve the actual Locale and/or Language in Android ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean the locale of the phone:

```
Locale myPhoneLocale = Locale.getDefault();
```